# Locking issues with "apt -y update && apt -y install python" in Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: apt, ubuntu-18.04

I'm creating an Ansible Playbook to set up Ubuntu 18.04.1 VPSs and am encountering a problem where I can't reliably install Python.

Since Ubuntu 18.04.1 is not shipping with Python installed, I'm forced to use the following command `apt -y update && apt -y install python` with the `raw` module.

I've also managed to get this error in a shell into which I manually ssh'd into.

```
root@ansible:~# apt -y update && apt -y install python
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
17 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

This is a Virtual Machine in VirtualBox on a Windows host.

I've also tried with using `sync` between `apt update` and `apt install`, even doing something like this `while fuser /var/lib/dpkg/lock >/dev/null 2>&1; do sync && sleep 1; done` between `update` and `install`, but it usually fails.

It is a system which has been set up with the following steps: https://askubuntu.com/questions/946787/ubuntu-server-installation-with-root-only/1066033#1066033

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 16.04+, iirc, ship with Python3 by default and have removed Python2 entirely from the default install; in other words, there is a functioning Python interpreter, it's just not in a place Ansible looks.

You can override the default behavior (expecting `python` as a command) by using the `ansible_python_interpreter` variable and setting it to, in the case of Ubuntu 16.04+, `/usr/bin/python3`.

So something like this:

`ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3`

Ansible now treats Python3 as a first-class citizen for the most part, so this is a pretty safe change.  I've been using it on a handful of Ubuntu 18.04 boxes I administer with no issues.